# How to add ObservableList data in textfield of JavaFX 8 (-like-: google search)?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8

I am new to javafx and need your help.
Company suggested me to add google search feature in our textbox.
so i picked the user textbox value searched it in database and stored back in  ObservableList, but how to append that ObservableList value in textbox so that it appear below textbox.

Extracting Textbox value and getting searched value from database, code overview -:

```
@FXML
public  TextField txtCustomerName;

private ObservableList<ItemGroup>  data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
System.out.println("Getting textvox value sucessfully ->"+value);
data=itemService.searchAction(value);
```

how to append "data" in textfield   txtCustomerName?

Complete Code -:

```
public void searchAction(String value)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside searchAction of abve address ->"+value);
        System.out.println("itemService=="+itemService);
        data=itemService.searchAction(value);

        ListView<ItemGroup> listView = new ListView<ItemGroup>(data);
        listView.setPrefSize(200, 250);
        listView.setEditable(true);

        listView.setItems(data);

}
```

I have tried with listView and set value to it but failed again to attach it with textarea. Please help me.

Comment: shardendu sir please help....

Comment: Well, what you need are : 1) put your listview into popup 2) allocate popup under textbox (look on samples on official oracle - javafx 8 tutorials)... This is an instance of solution, but you will understand direction to work with.

Comment: Then, add listview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(...) and put a selected item into textfield.

Comment: please suggest me url .. searching suggested topic leads to menu page of oracle